# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo about programmatically add row

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, dynamic-tables

I have a problem. I don't figure out that. I want to add dynamic row to tableLayout. My main acivity class :

```
public class DutyRoster extends Activity {
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        ArrayList<String> updateList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> totalDate, totalExam = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] temp = null; 
        webServiceCall wsc = new webServiceCall();
        TableLayout tablo;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_duty_roster);


        init();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.duty_roster, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void init() {

        tablo = (TableLayout)DutyRoster.this.findViewById(R.id.tablo);
        final  AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

        Button buton1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.remind);

        buton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (updateList.size() == 0) {

                    ad.setMessage("None selected!");
                } else {

                    startAnotherActivity();
                }
            }
        });


        try {

            String resp = wsc.Call();
            new SoapCall().execute(resp);

        }catch (Exception e) {

            ad.setTitle("Error!");
            ad.setMessage(e.toString());
            ad.show();
        }

            createDynamicTable(temp);

    }

    public void startAnotherActivity () {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, ScheduleActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putStringArrayList("updateList", updateList);
        i.putExtra("rowList", b);
        startActivity(i);

    }



   //add dynamic rows
    public void createDynamicTable(String[] tableContentList){


        for (int i = 0; i < tableContentList.length; i++){

            TableRow newLine = new TableRow(this);
            newLine.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView rowDate = new TextView(this);
            TextView rowName = new TextView(this);
            TextView rowPeriod = new TextView(this);

            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(checkBox));

            rowDate.setText(tableContentList[i]);
            rowName.setText(tableContentList[i + 1]);
            rowPeriod.setText(tableContentList[i + 2]);

            totalDate.add(tableContentList[i]);
            totalExam.add(tableContentList[i + 1]);

            newLine.addView(checkBox);
            newLine.addView(rowDate);
            newLine.addView(rowName);
            newLine.addView(rowPeriod);


            tablo.addView(newLine, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            i += 3;

        }

    }

    View.OnClickListener getOnClickDoSomething(final Button button) {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                int location = button.getId();
                updateList.add(totalDate.get(location) + "/" + totalExam.get(location));
            } 
        };
    }


//creating parallel process via AsyncTask structure
    private class SoapCall extends AsyncTask<String, String[], String[]> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(DutyRoster.this); 


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage("Loading..."); 
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] temp) {

            dialog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... responses) {
            String rsp = responses[0]; 

            String delimiter = "#"; 

            try{

                temp = rsp.split(delimiter); 

            }catch(Exception ex)
            {

                ex.printStackTrace();
            }   
            return temp; 
        }


    }
}
```

I'm getting the message **"The application Tickler(process omu.ceng.tickler) has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again"** while I'm running my code.

My layout file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tablo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="*" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/allCheckBox"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/date" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/name_of_exam" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/period_of_exam" />
                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/remind"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/remind" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So also I have some logs.

```
01-18 22:48:26.645: E/AndroidRuntime(717): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 22:48:26.645: E/AndroidRuntime(717): **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{omu.ceng.tickler/omu.ceng.tickler.DutyRoster}: java.lang.NullPointerException**
01-18 22:48:26.645: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-18 22:48:26.645: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-18 22:48:26.645: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-18 22:48:26.645: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-18 22:48:26.645: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-18 22:48:26.645: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-18 22:48:26.645: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-18 22:48:26.645: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 22:48:26.645: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-18 22:48:26.645: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-18 22:48:26.645: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-18 22:48:26.645: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 22:48:26.645: E/AndroidRuntime(717): **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException**
01-18 22:48:26.645: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at omu.ceng.tickler.DutyRoster.createDynamicTable(DutyRoster.java:109)
01-18 22:48:26.645: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at omu.ceng.tickler.DutyRoster.init(DutyRoster.java:85)
01-18 22:48:26.645: E/AndroidRuntime(717):  at omu.ceng.tickler.DutyRoster.onCreate(DutyRoster.java:38)
```

I think reason of error at the line => 
tablo = (TableLayout)DutyRoster.this.findViewById(R.id.tablo);
But I didn't find a solution.
Please, help me. I'm waiting for your suggestion.

Comment: Which is line 85? There is where the NullPointerException is firstly risen.

Comment: 85. line is **createDynamicTable(temp);**

Comment: Yeah, sorry at line 109 is the most nested point. What line is that?

Comment: It is the beginning of loop **for (int i = 0; i < tableContentList.length; i++)**

Comment: Yeah I counted the lines and figured it out :)  Check my answer

Comment: Did you have any progress on this? If you post the new Exception after my last comment you could help you further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field `temp` is null when you pass it in in `createDynamicTable(temp)`, and this blows up in the body of the method when you access `tableContentList.length`. The fact is, `AsyncTask` spawns another thread in the background that executes `doInBackground()`. Here you initialise the field `temp` but you cannot count on this happening before `createDynamicTable(temp)`.

Try calling `createDynamicTable(temp)` in `onPostExecute()` and remove line 85

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] temp) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    DutyRoster.this.temp = temp;
    createDynamicTable(temp);
}
```

By the way, watch out the leaks!

Comment: I'm sorry @Gil I wrote a little late because I was busy. Anyway I solved the error. It was about that I use web service. A method of web service returned wrong data so my loop had missing data. thank you for your help :)

Comment: Ok no worries, I like to help. If my answer helped solving the NullPointerException, please consider accepting it, so other people will have a ready solution when they google for the same problem. I'm glad your code works now :)